# Invite Facebook friends to use app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite-friends

I am trying to use `Facebook` `API` to enable `invite friends` to use my App
I used the Facebook Developers documentations .
The problem is that when the user invite his friends the `notifications` appears on those who use android native Facebook App 
but doesn't appear for the users that uses the `iOS` side.

**Here is my code**

```
 FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
        content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/<myAppLinkURL>"];
        //optionally set previewImageURL
        content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://img.youtube.com/vi/fuBhQX3ki1Q/mqdefault.jpg"];

        // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
        [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                                     delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add iOS iPhone Store Id in app's setting please have a look into attached screenshot. And also fill all to required information for ios when you are generating **AppUrlLink**

[image]